# jQuery focus locks focus in Angular4; Trying to set focus to first input error on page

Tags: jquery, angular

I am new to Angular, and I am attempting to use jQuery to set focus on the first error on a saved page. The jQuery I am using is as follows:

```
 $('#error1').parent().find('input').focus();
```

The page view moves to the desired element, and it does set the focus on that element.  The problem is that it **locks** the focus.  I cannot focus on any other input, nor can I scroll away from the focus.  This can't be the way jQuery is designed to work, can it?  I tried to release the focus with the following code:

```
setTimeout (() => {
               $('#error1').parent().find('input').blur();
            }, 1000);
```

This code, although it allows me to focus on other input elements, still does not allow me to scroll away from the original focus.  The page keeps returning to the spot of the original focus setting.  I am using Chrome as my browser.  Can anyone help with this?

A section of the HTML is as follows.  The input element is auto-created as 
part of the PrimeNg  template.  The error message(s) are shown on save when the entry is not made or is not valid.

```
<p-autoComplete *ngIf="editMode" [(ngModel)]="module.assigneeDetails.CTSRGTReviewAssigneeOne" (ngModelChange)="onDDLChange(module, module.assigneeDetails,'CTSRReviewOne')"  (onBlur)="checkUserValidation(module, module.assigneeDetails ,'CTSRReviewOne')" field="FullName" [dropdown]="true" (completeMethod)="searchUL($event,i, module.assigneeDetails.CTSRGTReviewAssigneeTwo)" (onDropdownClick)="handleULDropdown($event, module.assigneeDetails.CTSRGTReviewAssigneeTwo)" [suggestions]="filteredUserList">
                            <ng-template let-colval pTemplate="item">
                              <div innerHTML="{{colval.FullName}}"></div>
                            </ng-template>
                          </p-autoComplete>
                          <span *ngIf="!editMode"><span *ngIf="module.assigneeDetails.CTSRGTReviewAssigneeOne?.FullName !== this.translateService.instant('lbl_Select')">{{module.assigneeDetails.CTSRGTReviewAssigneeOne?.FullName}}</span></span>
                          <div class="errorMsg" [ngClass]="{'noError' : module.assigneeDetails.IsCTSRGTReviewAssigneeOne === false }" [hidden]="(module.assigneeDetails.IsCTSRGTReviewAssigneeOne === true)">{{'lbl_Error_Msg1'|translate}}</div>
```

Currently, I am using jQuery to highlight the input elements that are in error, and to set a unique id on each.  I then attempt, using the .focus() above, trying to direct the user to the first error.  That is the goal, to direct the user's focus to the first error on the page.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is no need to use `jQuery` with `Angular`

Comment: How would you do the above in Angular?  The input that I desire to set the focus on has no particular defining features, it is autocreated as part of a PrimeNG template.  That's why I locate it with jQuery.  I don't know how to "walk the Dom" in Angular.

Comment: add some more code to your question, change the title to what you *actually* want to do, and you might get better answers.